# How to: Change color of button when an input is given to a textbox

Tags: javascript, html, css

just learning JS and stuck here.

I have a textbox and a button. I want the color of the button to change (say red) whenever someone provides a value in the textbox. When the textbox is kept null, the color of button to remain in its initial color state.

Here is the code i wrote::

**HTML ::**

```js
    var text1 = document.getElementById("input1");
    var butt1 = document.getElementById("button1");
    
    if (text1.value == null || text1.value == "") {
      butt1.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }
    else {
      butt1.style.backgroundColor = "#F22613";
    }
```

```css
    #button1 {
      height: 20px;
      width: 100px;
      }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input1" value="xyz">
      <button type="submit" id="button1">
```

Comment: you need to have some event attached to your textbox and in that event you need write your code. you can use onChange event on the textbox

Answer (score 1):

You need to attach an event listener to the event `keyup` on the `textBox`

```js
var text1 = document.getElementById("input1");
var butt1 = document.getElementById("button1");

text1.addEventListener('keyup', function(){

  if (text1.value == null || text1.value == "") {
    butt1.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  }
  else {
    butt1.style.backgroundColor = "#F22613";
  }
});
```

```css
#button1 {
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="input1" value="xyz">
  <button type="submit" id="button1" >
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much bro! worked like a charm :)
Also, can you please explain me in brief about the **kyeup** feature??

Comment: @BeginnerKid `input` and many other elements have such a thing called 'event'.Every event has its callback function, which will work if the event is triggered: For more see http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html

Answer (score 0):

I was created function with `oninput` its will validate at the time of input you given

```js
function input(){
  var text1 = document.getElementById("input1");
var butt1 = document.getElementById("button1");

if (text1.value == null || text1.value == "") {
  butt1.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
else {
  butt1.style.backgroundColor = "#F22613";
}
}
```

```css
#button1 {
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input1" value="xyz" oninput="input()">
  <button type="submit" id="button1">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach `onChange` attribute to the textbox and assign a function to it. The function will be called, whenever `the value in the textbox is changed`. Here is the [codepen link](http://codepen.io/Aalind/pen/aBzReq).

Alternatively you can also assign an `eventlistener of keyup` on the textbox. You can find that solution in this [codepen link 2](http://codepen.io/Aalind/pen/MbYzYm).

```js
function myFunction(){
  var text1 = document.getElementById("input1");
var butt1 = document.getElementById("button1");
  if (text1.value == null || text1.value == "") {
    butt1.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  }
  else {
    butt1.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
}
```

```css
#button1 {
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input1" value="xyz" onchange="myFunction()">
<button type="submit" id="button1">Something</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Enter Press Test</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
        var text1 = document.getElementById("input1");
    var butt1 = document.getElementById("button1");

    text1.addEventListener('keyup', function(){

      if (text1.value == null || text1.value == "") {
        butt1.style.backgroundColor = "";
      }
      else {
        butt1.style.backgroundColor = "#F22613";
      }
    });
    };

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
     <input type="text" id="input1" value="">
     <button type="submit" id="button1">Submit</button>


   </body>
   </html>
```